# Wordpress. How can I view and send get/post requests in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress. How an I view and send get/post requests in php?

This plugin's code is not working:

I wrote this plugin. it is all the source code.

Plugin's file index.php

this function could be start on the activate plugin:

```
function activate() {
    // registration
        $post = array(
              //'ID'             => 15, // Are you updating an existing post?
              'post_content'   => '
              <form action="#" method="post">
                <p>
                  <label for="username">username: </label>
                  <input type="text" id="username" /><br />
                  <label for="nick">password: </label>
                  <input type="text" id="password" /><br />
                   <label for="password_repeat">repeat_password: </label>
                  <input type="text" id="repeat_password" /><br />
                  <label for="email">Email: </label>
                  <input type="text" id="email" /><br />
                  <label for="age">Возраст </label>
                  <input type="text" id="age" /><br />
                  <input type="submit" value="Enter">
                </p>
                   </form>
              ', // The full text of the post.
              'post_name'      => 'reg', // The name (slug) for your post
              'post_title'     => 'reg', // The title of your post.
              'post_status'    => 'publish', // Default 'draft'.
              'post_type'      => 'page', // Default 'post'.
         ); 
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate' );



function market () {

        $user_login = $_POST['user_login'];
        $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];

    $test = "testesttest";
    return $test;
}
//add_action( 'init', 'register_form' );
add_action( 'get_header', 'market' );
```

Comment: Please provide more information for what you tried so far, which plugin are you using and so on

Answer (score 0):

to view post and get requests you can use the debug bar plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/

Answer (score 0):

I need it in my php code:

```
function sitemarket () {

            if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
                header('Allow: POST');
                header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
                header('Content-Type: text/plain');
                exit;
        }


        nocache_headers();
        var_dump($_POST);
        $comment = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : "";
        var_dump($comment);

    //$test = authentication("user123","user951");


    $test = "testesttest";
    return $test;
}
//add_action( 'init', 'register_form' );
add_action( 'get_header', 'sitemarket' );
```

Why POST REQUEST = NULL ?